# I am interested in "merging" two separate projects in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two separate projects, project A (a razor page site) and project B (web API). Project B came a while after Project A was created, and I did not think at the time the annoyance of having to bounce between the two in VS for referencing. I do run Project B completely off of the DBO of Project A.

So I was wondering what, if any, my options would be to either merge the two together in a solution, or would a total recreation of both projects into a single solution be an answer?

The server is a host running IIS, I have both projects in respective sub directories and separate app pools. It would not be ideal to be working on Project A and wanting to publish Project A, but also have to publish Project B.

I have not had a good run searching around, Im not even particularly sure what Im asking is feasible, or if what Im asking is the right thing to ask. I am open to better ideas, or actual legible ideas, or "suck it up and switch between projects accordingly".

Comment: Are the two projects in the same solution?  If not, do that first.

Comment: You have a solution for project A. Then, you add the existing project B
You now want to access the file from B A. If this is the case, right click on B -> References and add a reference to project A. You can use files from this project.

Comment: I wonder why cut/paste cannot be done by you to merge the two projects if you like. If there is anything special of your projects, edit the question to show them.

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your concern:**

> It would not be ideal to be working on Project A and wanting to publish Project A, but also have to publish Project B.

With modern Continuous Deployment tools publishing only one of the projects should be a matter of a mouse click, a true/false option for each project in the release pipline. But check this with your tech of choice before the merge.

After all, every C# project becomes a DLL (then nuget) or an EXE. It is up to you whether you build and "*copy*" that .exe to the server or client machine.

**To answer you question:**

> So I was wondering what, if any, my options would be to either merge the two together in a solution...

It is as simple as:

- (optional: move the project folder of B to the solution folder of A),
- right click on the solution and choose *Add*, then *Existing Project* (see picture),
- select the csproj file.

[image: visual studio solution right click menu, showing 'add existing project']

**Further optimization possibility:**

I assume you rebuild project B everytime project A changes, or at least when the referenced files are. I recommend you create a 3. project in the merged solution, a class library ("C") instead, where you move those files in need of being referenced. Obviously, when you change Project C, you will need to rebuild both A and B.